# Why I can't create a context menun using dojo over google maps

Tags: google-maps, dojo

I want to create a context menu using Dojo over google maps.But it doesn't work over the map but in other elements the context menu works.

I try to create a google maps listener:

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'rightclick', funcition(){create_menu("mapa_div")})

But it doesn't work too

Any advise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think then, this below format should work well.

```
new dijit.Menu({
        targetNodeIds: ["id_of_the_domNode_containing_the_map"]
    });
```

Comment: hanks for answer, but the function create_menu("mapa_div") has this code line. And... "id_of_the_domNode_containing_the_map"= "mapa_div". When I force a code error in the google listener the menu is showed. Any idea? it seems a fight between google maps listener and dojo menu....?

Comment: if you have the above code in your create_menu function, then there is no need for google.maps.event.addListener, because through "google.maps.event.addListener" you are trying to attach right click for the map, Again in create_menu an right click is getting attached by dojo because of targetNodeIds.

Comment: it doesn´t show in the map, in other objects it's showed. So I decided to try whith google listener, but it doesn't work